# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu

Tags: 32bit-64bit

I want to install netgen and try to compile the source code.
During this I got the error message:

```
U -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltk8.6 -ltcl8.6 -lGL -lXmu -lX11 -fopenmp -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/netgen/lib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [netgen] Error 1
```

Maybe I have to install an additional package?
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can check, depending on your specific OS, if you are not missing the missing the non-versioned named (i.e. `libXmu.so`).

Check for `ls /usr/lib/libXmu*.*`, and if not found, type:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libXmu.so libXmu.so.6
ln -s /usr/lib/libXuu.so libXmuu.so.1
```

If you don't have any `libXmu*.*` files, then you need to install first [`libxmu-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libxmu-dev):

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Unfortunately it did not work. 
I checked for the files '/usr/lib/libXmu.so' and '/usr/lib/libXuu.so' and could not found them although libxmu-headers and stuff is installed.
Any suggestions? Maybe I should reinstall it?

Comment: @user3528789 Do you have any `libXmu*.*` file at all?

Comment: thanks a lot. now the building process runs further. but i am stuck again. The error message I get is:
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libTogl.so: undefined reference to 'Tk_InitStubs'` and 
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libTogl.so: undefined reference to 'tclStubsPtr'`
Do you have any idea about that? May be I have to make adjustments to the make file?
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libTogl.so: undefined reference to 'tkStubsPtr'`
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libTogl.so: undefined reference to 'Tcl_InitStubs'`

Comment: @user3528789 the comment to your question says what is missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334781/libtogl-undefined-references#comment41335571_26334781