# Trouble executing C++ makefile in Linux (works fine on mac)

Tags: c++, linux, macos, makefile, glut

When I run `make` I get the following:

```
> make
g++ -g me.o -L/opt/PDmesa/Mesa-5.0.1/lib 
            -L/opt/PDmesa/GLUT-3.7/lib 
            -L/usr/X11R6/lib 
            -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -lXext -lXmu -lXi -lm 
            -o me

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [me] Error 1`
```

Its a c++ program I wrote which use glut libs. I installed those but I don't understand what else is missing as the dependencies were also installed.

Comment: You are missing the development libraries for those two libraries. Did you install the `-dev` or `-devel` packages too?

Comment: If you installed them using the normal tools they should end up in `/usr/local/lib` or `/opt/lib` depending on your flavor of linux. http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/fhs.html

Comment: You may want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26322603/14065

Comment: Thanks, although I had installed some libs, I was missing the -dev versions.

Answer (score 0):

although I had installed some libs, I was missing the -dev versions. – André